# How to search a file inside awk

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have 2 seperate files lostType.txt (shows the selected options), and lost.txt (shows the memory leaks) I am using [dialog](http://hightek.org/dialog/) to create GUI. Using checkboxes, I am taking some number intervals from user to limit memory leaks that will be printed.  What I have to do is, print the lines which memory leak is in selected size, and leak type is in lostType.txt

For example, this is `lost.txt`

```
LEAK SUMMARY
100 bytes definitely lost
0 bytes indirectly lost
0 bytes possibly lost
100 bytes still reachable
0 bytes suppressed
```

If user wants to see definetely lost, and indirect lost, `lostType.txt` has the following

```
definetely
indirectly
```

Suppose user selected to see leaks, where size is between 0 and 10 bytes OR 100 and 250 bytes. Now the output must be `100 bytes in 1 blocks definitely lost`

What I did so far is the following,

```
for choice in $choices
do
    case $choice in
    1)
        #"Memory Leak <= 10 Byte"
        cat lost.txt | awk '{
            if ($1 <= 10 && $1 > 0 )
                print $1,$2" ==>",$3,$4     
            }'
        ;;

    2)
        #"10 Byte < Memory Leak <= 50 Byte"
        cat lost.txt | awk '{
            if ($1 <= 50 && $1 > 10 )
                print $1,$2" ==>",$3,$4     
            }'
        ;;
```

That is, depending on the selected size interval, I can print the values. However, I couldn't find a way to look for lostType ($3 for upper code). What I need to do is searching the file in awk like

```
cat lost.txt | awk '{
 if ($1 <= 50 && $1 > 10 AND IF $3 IS IN lostType.txt)
      print $1,$2" ==>",$3,$4   
 }'
;;
```

So my question is, how can I search a file inside awk?

Comment: Pls. avoid the use of `cat file | awk ...`. Use `awk ... file` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, the following `awk` command should work. You must provide both input files. Lost types are saved in a hash and compare the key with third field of the other one.

```
awk '
    FNR == NR { type[ $1 ] = 1; next } 
    $1 > 10 && $1 < 200 && type[ $3 ] { print $1,$2 " ==> " $3,$4 }
' lostType.txt lost.txt
```

But this way you would parse both for every `case` option. In my opinion should be a better solution to pass those variables to the `awk` command and run it only once.

```
case $choice in
1)
    limit_inf=0
    limit_sup=10
    break
    ;;
2)
    limit_inf=10
    limit_sup=50
    break
    ;;
...
```

And then:

```
awk -v li="$limit_inf" -v ls="$limit_sup" '
    FNR == NR { type[ $1 ] = 1; next } 
    $1 > li && $1 < ls && type[ $3 ] { print $1,$2 " ==> " $3,$4 }
' lostType.txt lost.txt
```